# Not able to 'link_to' specific routes in code, but can access them by manually entering them into the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Am relatively new to Rails and have run into a problem I can't seem to solve.

I have setup a nested resource Model called `Captable`. It belongs_to a Company.

If I navigate to a certain view: for example `http://localhost:3000/companies/9/captables/1` - everything works great. I see the right data.

I have 2 core problems I can't seem to solve, that I think have something to do with either naming conventions or routes.

Firstly, when I try access `http://localhost:3000/companies/9/captables/new` - I get the following error.

```
NoMethodError in Captables#new
Showing /Users/jamespember/calmcap/app/views/captables/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `captables_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f8a08edebc8>:0x00007f8a0984bfa8>
Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5
6


<%= form_with(model: @captable, local: true) do |form| %>

  <% if @captable.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
```

Secondly - if I try link to link to the `company_captables_path`from the `/companies/` page by using the below, I get the following error.

```
View Cap Table: <%= link_to(@company.company_captables_path) %>
```

Error:

```
 Showing /Users/jamespember/calmcap/app/views/companies/show.html.erb where line #30 raised:

undefined method `company_captables_path' for #<Company:0x00007f8a046a6630>
```

---

### Here's some code snippets:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  get 'dashboard/index'

  root 'companies#index'

  resources :companies do
    resources :shareholders
    resources :captables
  end

end
```

**captable.rb**

```
class Captable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

**captables_controller.rb**

```
class CaptablesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_captable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @captables = Captable.all 
  end

  def show
    @captable = Captable.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @captable = Captable.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @captable = Captable.new(captable_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @captable.save
        format.html { redirect_to @captable, notice: 'Captable was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @captable }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @captable.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @captable.update(captable_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @captable, notice: 'Captable was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @captable }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @captable.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @captable.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to captables_url, notice: 'Captable was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_captable
      @captable = Captable.find(params[:id])
    end

    def captable_params
      params.require(:captable).permit(:version, :name, :company_id)
    end
end
```

**captables/show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Version:</strong>
  <%= @captable.version %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @captable.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Company:</strong>
  <%= @captable.company_id %>
</p>
```

**captables/_form.html.erb - EDIT Updated**

```
<%= form_with(model: [@company, @captable], local: true) do |form| %>

  <% if @captable.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@captable.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @captable.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**schema.rb**

Here's the schema for the table:

```
  create_table "captables", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "version"
    t.text "name"
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**Lastly, here's a screenshot of my `rails routes`.**

[image]

**Error when trying to access `/companies/:id/captables/new`**

[image]

Comment: can you show the code for both show and form?

Comment: as far as i know, path variables are not instance methods. i think you want to pass a parameter to the path?

Comment: Added both the show and form snippets now.

Comment: Given that I can access the specific pages i.e `http://localhost:3000/companies/9/captables/1`  but I cannot access the new page - `http://localhost:3000/companies/9/captables/new` - I think you're right. There must be something broken in the form.... Any ideas?

Comment: @KoU_warch, they are instance methods - but they are called to the view context (the implicit self in your views) or on the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails route helper methods are added to the view context and controller - not models.

The link should read:

```
<%= link_to("Link text", company_captables_path(@company)) %>
```

Which is an implicit call to to:

```
<%= link_to("Link text", self.company_captables_path(@company)) %>
```

`self` being the view context.

When creating a form for a nested route you should pass an array:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@company, @captable], local: true) do |form| %>
   # ...
<% end %>
```

You should also create the new instance from the assocation:

```
class CaptablesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company
  before_action :set_captable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /companies/:company_id/captables/new
  def new
    @captable = @company.captables.new
  end

  # POST /companies/:company_id/captables
  # POST /companies/:company_id/captables.json
  def create
    @captable = @company.captables.new(captable_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @captable.save
        format.html { redirect_to @captable, notice: 'Captable was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @captable }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @captable.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end

    # ...
end
```

Comment: OK great, thank you. the `link_to` now works great. I can successfully access the index page of `/company/id/captables`.

However, I still get the same error as above when trying to access `/company/id/captables/new` - that `NoMethodError in Captables#new`. I assume then the new method in my captables_controller is broken. You can see it in the code above.

Comment: Did you change the form to use an array and ensure that `@company` is set?

Comment: Yep, same problem. Edited _form snippet above.

Comment: I can verify that `form_with(model: [@company, @captable], local: true)` works. I'm guessing that you did not check that @company is actually set and not nil as `form_with(model: [nil, @captable], local: true)` will result in that error.

Comment: Setting the company within the captable_controller seems to be the fix in addition to editing the new and create methods! 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The only thing that didn't work was the `redirect_to @captable`. That threw an error -->  `NoMethodError in CaptablesController#create
undefined method `captable_url'`- but I think I can probably get around that somehow!

Comment: Its the same when redirecting: `redirect_to [@company, @captable]`. The link helpers, forms and redirects all use [`ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) so you can use the same signature everywhere.